# Array explode json

Tags: php, arrays, json, explode

I would like to generate json from form data. This is what i have:

```
<?php
$data = explode(',', $data);
$accounts = [];

foreach ($data as $split) {
     $split = explode(':', $split);
     $accounts['username'] = trim($split[0]);
     $accounts['password'] = $split[1];
}

var_dump(json_encode($accounts));
```

The problem is that it only does the last element in the loop. I know why it does that, but im overlooking something and cant get it right.. I want the json to be this;

```
{
  "Username": "username",
  "Password": "username"
},
{
  "Username": "username",
  "Password": "password"
},
```

etc etc. What the best way to approach this? I'm prob not thinking right..

Comment: As you already know you overwrite your array keys each iteration. You probably want to do something like this: `$accounts[] = ["Username" => trim($split[0]), "Passowrd" => $split[1]];` Also I would recommend that you place `print_r($accouns);` into your foreach loop and once after it and do it with your current code now and with the code change I suggested above to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) way with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) *(that is nothing more than an implicit loop)*:

```
$data = 'username1:pass1, user2:pass2, uesr3:pass3';

$accounts = array_map(function ($account) {
    list($user, $pass) = explode(':', $account);
    return [ 'username' => trim($user), 'password' => $pass ];
}, explode(',', $data));

echo json_encode($accounts);
```

Comment: Nice way of doing that! Will use this! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = explode(',', $data);
$accounts = [];

foreach ($data as $key=>$split) {
    $split = explode(':', $split);
    $accounts[$key]['username'] = trim($split[0]);
    $accounts[$key]['password'] = $split[1];
}

var_dump(json_encode($accounts));
```

See the updated code example; in your original code you are overwriting your $accounts array every iteration, that's why the last element of the loop shows when you var_dump.  In adding the key, you map the values to a new multi dimensional array.

Comment: Take a look at my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519821/array-explode-json#comment72176678_42519821 If you rewrite the code a bit you don't have to use the `$key` variable. Also showing how the `$accounts` array changes with your code and with OP's code might visualize it better what you changed in your code and what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! Its working :) Knew it would be something like this.. :l